# Accidentally added a library to NetBeans IDE and now I can't remove it

Tags: netbeans, libraries

I was trying to find and answer to a previous problem I had and accidentally added a library which includes all of the AppData folder from my computer. Now there is a constant background scanning of projects running, which I can't stop, and I can't remove the library from the project folder.

Can someone tell me what I should do?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from nbprojects/project.properties? (Make a backup before editing)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14545_01/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.doc/html/j2eelib/operations/opRemoveLibRefFromClasspath.html) to remove library from the project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqYLb.png)

Right click it, then click Properties.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HlXM.png)

Select the Folder or Jar file youve added in your library and click Remove Button